# String Not Allocated when Accessing

Tags: c, opengl, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following code:

```
// Get characters of file
int numChars = 0;
while(fgetc(file) != EOF)
    numChars++;

// Allocate memory for shader string
char * shaderString = malloc(numChars * sizeof(char));

// Rewind file to read in string
rewind(file);

// Read in file
while((*shaderString++ = fgetc(file)) != EOF);

printf("Shader to compile:\n%s\n", shaderString);

// Make shader
GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shaderType);
glShaderSource(shader, 1, &shaderString, NULL);
glCompileShader(shader);

printf("Shader compiled:\n%s\n", shaderString);
```

For some reason, the string `shaderString` doesn't seem to be accessible by either the `printf` or `glShaderSource` calls. Another interesting thing is that when I try to call `free(shaderString)`, I get an error about no memory being allocated. Typically I get nothing in the print statements, or occasionally a question mark or random text, so I feel like it must be something simple I am missing. If I add a `puts(*(shaderString-1))` with the while loop that assigns the string, it prints the shader file as it should, though occasionally with random OpenGL info.

**EDIT:** After running the code with lldb, I have found the contents of the `shaderString` variables to be `"ot foun\x05"` and `"\x04\x01"` when loading two different files, which seems to possibly go along with an end of file like I never called `rewind(file)`, but that doesn't explain how trying the `puts(*(shaderString-1))` works.

Comment: Why do you expect that `shaderString` still points to the start of the string after you incremented it?

Comment: @RetoKoradi I seemed to overlook that, but realizing it fixed the main issue that I was having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Get characters of file
    int numChars = 0;
    while(fgetc(file) != EOF)
        numChars++;

    // Allocate memory for shader string
    char * shaderString = malloc(numChars * sizeof(char) +1 ); // +1 for '\0'

    // Rewind file to read in string
    rewind(file);

    // if no pTemp, u can't find the start of your string
    char* pTemp = shaderString;
    // Read in file
    while((*pTemp++ = fgetc(file)) != EOF);
    *pTemp = '\0';

    printf("Shader to compile:\n%s\n", shaderString);
```

some error.

Comment: Is it necessary to always have the null terminator on the end of a char pointer if it is a string? Also, do you know what could be causing me to get a question mark at the end of my string? I assume it is an encoding issue, but reading the file with `cat -v` didn't show any control characters or anything at the end of the file.

Comment: without the null terminator, c\c++ don't know here is the end of this string. c\c++ use C-Style string whose ending mark with the null terminator.

Comment: If the last argument of `glShaderSource()` is non-NULL, it is used as an array of string lengths. So you could pass in strings without the `'\0'` terminator if you pass in the string length. But terminating the strings is normally easier than passing in an additional argument.